# Trying to get a replacement set of probes for an old multimeter

Tags: multimeter, probe

Summary:

- I am looking for the correct terminology to describe probes from an obsolete multimeter so that I can use this information to find replacements myself.
- I am not asking for specific recommendations or site links. If I happened to receive such along the way it would be a bonus BUT I'm really asking for specific technical information.

---

I've got an analogue multimeter that I've had for years that I happen to like - I know it's fairly old, but I can keep it in the small tool kit that I cart around. It's perfectly acceptable for low voltage, quick jobs when I don't need great accuracy and it doesn't have a battery that I'll forget to change or could leak. Basically it's a decent spare meter.

Recently the black probe lead had a fight with a soldering iron and lost. I'm now on the lookout for a replacement set of probes.

The problem is the jack plug that connects the probe lead to the meter is only 2mm in diameter. All the replacement probes I've seen on-line use a 4mm banana plug (assuming they even bother saying what size the plug is at all). I know this is standard for modern multimeters, but I'd still like to be able use my old meter.

Searching for phrases like "multimeter probes 2mm jack" bring up loads of result for probes with a 4mm jack and a 2mm probe head, which isn't what I need.

Question: Can anyone advise me what the proper names or terminology are for these old style probes so that I can search for them myself?

Comment: Search the Interwebs using "2mm mini banana plug dmm probes". You can also find 4mm banana jack to 2mm pin tip plug adapters, which would allow you to use multimeter test leads that have 4mm banana plugs.  FWIW, think twice before measuring AC line voltage with older multimeters and older test leads.  Older equipment is often noncompliant with modern "CAT" safety standards (e.g., CAT II, CAT III, etc.) and is hazardous to use when measuring certain AC voltages.  See also: https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/what-are-multimeter-cat-safety-ratings

Comment: 4mm to 2mm adapters are available. Modern probes have sheathed pins (for safety) which may be incompatible. Possibly they can be modified but that compromises safety, of course.

Comment: There are vendors that make replacement probes to order as direct replacements for older test equipment.   Here is one example, perhaps your older model is included in their replacement list.    https://probemaster.com/meter-to-test-lead/

Comment: I believe the 2 mm banana diameter plugs are called "miniature banana" or "mini banana". Search on Digikey for mini banana.

Comment: Thanks everybody - I think the probes are harder to find my side of the Atlantic, but I've now found a set. I think a big part of the problem was that searches for "probe" always return results about the probe head, but if I search for "banana" I get a mixture of connectors for either end of the leads

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been close, but my question is NOT looking "recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them". My question is trying to find the correct terminology so I can search my self.

Comment: @Stormcloud Asking for places to search is also off topic. We typically answer design questions on this site. A question on how to repair electrical test equipment is on topic as long as you aren't asking where to  get the repair or what to look for.

Comment: @Voltage Spike, I did not ask for for places to search. This partly because I know that is off topic, but also because living in Europe means that any US centric answers I got wouldn't help me. My question was to get the exact name of the thing to search for. People who design and (more importantly) implement electronic circuits will know this, but as a hobbyist I don't. As I am not the only hobbyist this *IS* a generally useful question.

Comment: @Stormcloud - Hi, I understand it can be frustrating to have a question closed. However your approach of editing meta text into the question is *not allowed* and it has been removed. It crossed the line into site abuse (bumping the question in that way with meta updates) so, please, don't repeat that. Questions on the main site should contain *only* the technical question. || Also IMHO those (increasingly demanding) updates are more likely to be turning people *off* from your appeal, than they are helping your case. || To reopen a closed question, see [here](/help/reopen-questions).

Comment: You've done points 1 & 2. (Note it says to put your appeal in a *comment* - it does *not* say to put your appeal into the question itself.) It was closed by community voting so point 3 doesn't apply. You can't do point 4. That leaves making an appeal on our [Meta]. If you do post an appeal on our Meta explaining why you don't believe the question should be closed, please treat it like point 1 i.e. be constructive. Rhetoric is unlikely to help. || On first glance, some of the *early* (now deleted) updates to the question (you can find them in the edit history) could be used in the appeal. TY

Comment: @VoltageSpike: "as you aren't asking where to get the repair or what to look for" is wrong.  "what to look for", which is what this question asked, is allowed as long as it isn't requesting a part selection.  Don't lump it in with "where".

Comment: @BenVoigt asking where to look or for what to look for is not on topic they're both shopping questions it's not my call I would prefer a question like this to be on topic Jeff Atwood does not

Comment: @VoltageSpike: "product recommendation questions" are off-topic.  That means no "what ADC model should I use?".  Even then, an answer can recommend "I think you need a Texas Instruments ADC model 123456".  Specs for the OP to go look for often occurs during design advice and those are definitely on-topic e.g. "This approach needs a sigma-delta ADC with at least 50 MHz bandwidth and 24 bit precision, AC-coupled to your electrodes".

Comment: My response is here: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/question-repeatedly-closed-no-sensible-reason-given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there are a few Ebay sources of test leads with 2mm end plugs.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/225058045199

https://www.ebay.com/p/1487001049

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are looking for is known as a pin tip plug, which has a 2 mm solid pin that mates with a spring loaded jack. Like this:

https://www.pomonaelectronics.com/sites/default/files/d5173_1_01.pdf

[image: Pin plug]

https://www.pomonaelectronics.com/products/banana-plugs-jacks-and-hardware/pin-jacks-and-plugs

[image: Pin plug]

Comment: There *are* also 2 mm "mini" banana plugs, which have the spring on the plug end and a smooth socket. I think those are a bit rarer than tip plugs though.

Comment: I think those are miniature banana plugs, which are 3 mm diameter. https://www.pomonaelectronics.com/sites/default/files/d2944_100.pdf (edit) They also have 2 mm banana plugs: https://www.pomonaelectronics.com/sites/default/files/d5936_101.pdf